# mysql form subarray(array aggregation) and return

Tags: mysql, arrays, aggregate, sub-array

I have the following mysql query

```
    select  m.flat_id,
            f.flat_no,
            fo.owner_name,
            oc.occupant_name,
            b.block_name,
            f.floor_no,
            f.floor_id,
            m.user_id as user_map_id

    from svk_apt_flats_users_mapping m
    left join svk_apt_users u on u.user_id = m.user_id and u.association_id = 2 
        and u.customer_id = 2 and u.is_active = 1 and u.user_id is not null
    left join svk_apt_flats f on f.flat_id = m.flat_id and f.is_active = 1
    left join svk_apt_blocks b on b.block_id = f.block_id and b.is_active = 1
    left join svk_apt_flat_owners fo on u.user_role_type_id = 4 and fo.is_active = 1 and fo.user_id = m.user_id
    left join svk_apt_occupants oc on u.user_role_type_id = 5 and oc.is_active = 1 and oc.user_id = m.user_id 

where   f.block_id = 3
        and m.user_id <> 2
        and m.customer_id = 2
        and m.association_id = 2 
        and m.is_active = 1
        and m.is_active = 1
        and (case when m.user_role_type_id = 5 then true else m.is_approved = 1 end)
```

and Output :
[image]

I want to aggregate the rows who have same 'user_map_id' into one row. 
Is there any solutions in mysql ?

Comment: You should also tell us what output you expect, because that will likely determine what the query would be.  By the way, you don't need to post such a complex query; a simplified version would be just fine, so long as it can get your point across.

Comment: expected output is "Displaying repeated 'user_map_id' and it's rows in one row".

Comment: If you aggregate or group user_map_id, what other columns do you wish to return in query? Like do you need sum of some column or concatenation ? or anything else .

Comment: yes, I need to concatenate rows who have same user_map_id in subarray, just like "array_agg() function in Postgresql"

Answer (score 0):

Use group by

```
    select  m.flat_id,
            f.flat_no,
            fo.owner_name,
            oc.occupant_name,
            b.block_name,
            f.floor_no,
            f.floor_id,
            m.user_id as user_map_id

    from svk_apt_flats_users_mapping m
    left join svk_apt_users u on u.user_id = m.user_id and u.association_id = 2 
        and u.customer_id = 2 and u.is_active = 1 and u.user_id is not null
    left join svk_apt_flats f on f.flat_id = m.flat_id and f.is_active = 1
    left join svk_apt_blocks b on b.block_id = f.block_id and b.is_active = 1
    left join svk_apt_flat_owners fo on u.user_role_type_id = 4 and fo.is_active = 1 and fo.user_id = m.user_id
    left join svk_apt_occupants oc on u.user_role_type_id = 5 and oc.is_active = 1 and oc.user_id = m.user_id 

where   f.block_id = 3
        and m.user_id <> 2
        and m.customer_id = 2
        and m.association_id = 2 
        and m.is_active = 1
        and m.is_active = 1
        and (case when m.user_role_type_id = 5 then true else m.is_approved = 1 end)
group by u.user_role_type_id;
```

MySQL will pick the values of the first row for all columns if you do not specifiy an aggregate function like SUM, AVG etc. onto them

Comment: it's not working. Please observe the column 'm.user_id as user_map_id' in select statement which is repeated three times. I want to form one row for repeated 'user_id' along with rows into one row.

Comment: So what happens if you use group by m.user_id or group by user_map_id ?

Comment: group by m.user_id removes repeated user_id and it's rows. But I want to concatenate those rows in one row to form sub array.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get, what output you expect. Can you add the expected output in form of a table?